# VBA Create Matrix from Multiple ListBox containing headers

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a ListBox where are some columns names, and I'd like to build a matrix with only the selected columns in it. Is there a simple way to do that?

I'm actually trying with :

```
Dim Matrix_a() As Variant
J = 0

For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
       J = J + 1
       Matrix_a.Columns(J) = Price.Columns(i)
    End If
Next i
```

where "Price" is a previously defined range. this doesn't work because of an "incorrect qualificator", but I don't see how to bypass that (my VBA level being quite low).

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

many issues here:

1. since you have declared `Matrix_a` as a dynamic array, you need to dimension it before use
2. you dont need the `.Columns` reference to `Matrix_a`
3. ListBox proerty is `Column`, not `Columns`
4. the ListBox `Selected` property applies to rows, not columns

Dim'ing an array

```
'Declaration
Dim Matrix_a() As Variant

' Set a size
Redim Matrix_a(0 to 1, 0 to 1)

' Resize, keeping any existing data intact
Redim Preserve Matrix_a(0 to 1, 0 to 2)

' you can use variables
i = 3
Redim Preserve Matrix_a(0 to 1, 0 to i)

' Note: you can only change the last dimenstion with Preserve
' Having declared (0 to 1, 0 to 1), this won't work:
Redim Preserve Matrix_a(0 to 2, 0 to 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but there are still things I don't understand : 1. How do I ReDim Matrix_a if I don't know exactly how many columns will be selected ? 4. Does it change anything? As i is a number I want to select the ith column from Price.

Comment: @Jack added examples of array dim'ing to answer.  As to the "...select the i'th column from Price...", how do you plan on selecting columns in the ListBox?  Remember that `Selected` refers to rows

Comment: Thanks for your addings, I'm actually doing it like this and it seems to work : 'nRow = UBound(Price)
nCol = 0
For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
       nCol = nCol + 1
    End If
Next i

ReDim Matrix_a(nRow, nCol)

nCol = 0
For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
       nCol = nCol + 1
       For r = 1 To nRow
        Matrix_a(r, nCol) = Price(r, i)
       Next r
    End If
Next i'. Thanks for all! edit: How do I make the code formating right?